# Accessing values of GeoTIFF in R?

Tags: r

I have several geoTIFFs that I want to sum by band (6 different bands) but I can not access to the values to sum them.

I open the geoTIFF:

```
# work with raster data
library(raster)
# export GeoTIFFs and other core GIS functions
library(rgdal)

# Use stack function to read in all bands
data <- stack("2012-01-23.tif")

# view raster attributes
data@layers

# view attributes for one band
data[[1]]
```

Then I see only this information:

```
[[1]]
class       : RasterLayer 
band        : 1  (of  6  bands)
dimensions  : 1800, 3600, 6480000  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
extent      : -180, 180, -90, 90  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : C:\1. Documentos\2012-01-23.tif 
names       : X2012.01.23.1
```

and I do not know how to access to the values inside each band. In some examples I have notice that after names there is another variable called values, but I do not have it.

Comment: You really need to read the vignette for the raster package at: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/raster/vignettes/Raster.pdf The short answer is: sum(getValues(data[[1]]),na.rm=TRUE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are first-class objects  and have first class methods. See `?values` and try `names(data)`, and  `subset(data, names(data)[1])`, which is equivalent to `data[[1]]`. Note that `values(data[[1]])` comes out in left-to-right, top-to-bottom order so you can get more nuanced with `?extract` i.e. `extract(data, query-object)` or `extract(data, cell-index)`, and in particular `extract(data[[1]], seq_len(ncell(data)))` is the same as `values(data[[1]])`.

All the extract idioms generalize to multiple layers in a straightforwardish way (a matrix with values for each layer down columns).

To sum a layer, use

```
sum(values(data[[1]]))
```

or more generally

```
calc(data, fun, args)
```

e.g.

```
calc(data, sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

`?calc` handles the application across "layers".

Note, just a side-track to explain why the terminology is so confusing and weird here. These "multi-layer" rasters are 3D arrays presented like tables of columns, and what we might call a "slice" in an array is called a "layer", behaving like a "column". This is awful because some rasters inherently have "multiple columns", i.e. a 3-component image will have at least Red, Green, Blue *layers*, but remember we used this axis for the 3rd dimension. So, this leaves "no more dimensions" and we are stuck, we cannot have a time-varying RGB image, for example. Development of "quads" in raster is stalled, but really it's never going to transcend the dimensions/columns conflation that is standard in GIS-y tools. The whole thing needs rethinking and the right "virtual model" is for dimensions to continue "down the columns", leaving sideways for extra variables.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest answer is `sum(rasterobj@file@nbands)`.

To check extra values within the layers of most S4 objects, you have to search by :

```
object@layer$columnORvalue
```

**OR**

```
object@layer@value
```

just depends on the type of S4 object, like the answer above explains.